# save position of draggable li jQuery Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, draggable

I have page with a map on my web-site where administrator can drag and drop icons to the specific position. After reading some examples, icons can be draggable, but when i try to refresh the page all icons revert to their default positions. I can't figure out how to save the position of elements to the database. I'm using jQuery and Rails 3. Help me please!

Thank you!

Here's the code of my page:

```
<div class="map">
    <ul class="departments-map" id="departments-map">
        <%= render :partial => 'departments/departments_short_map', :collection => @departments %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Departments_short_map:

```
<% department ||= departments_short_map %>
<% if department.map_x.nil? or department.map_y.nil? %>
    <li id="<%= department.id %>" class="department-short-map">
        <%= department_for_collage(department) %>
    </li>
<% else %>
    <li id="<%= department.id %>" class="department-short-map" style="position:absolute; top:#{ department.map_y}px; left:#{ department.map_x}px;">
        <%= department_for_collage(department) %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

And here is my jQuery code:

```
var Collage = {
    init: function() {
        $("#departments-map li").draggable({
            scroll: false,
            stop: function(event, ui) {
                var img = {
                    "id": $(this).attr('id'),
                    "map_y": $(this).position().top.toString(),
                    "map_x": $(this).position().left.toString()
                };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "put",
                    url: "/departments/" + $(this).attr('id') + ".json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(img),
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    dataType: 'json',
                })
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I find out what was my mistake! Who is interesting:
1. <li id="<%= department.id %>" class="department-short-map" style="position:absolute; top:<%= department.map_y %>px; left:<%= department.map_x %>px;">
2. I forget to add :map_x and :map_y to attr_accessible in Department model